# Inverse Output of Recursive function C++

Tags: c++

I have written a functions that outputs the prime factors of a number entered by the user. The output i am getting is correct, however the output is backwards.

For example the input is 1776: output => 2 x 2 x 2 x 2 x 3 x 37 x

The output I'm looking for is => 37 x 3 x 2 x 2 x 2 x 2

how can I inverse the output and remove the extra multiplication symbol (x) behind 37.

```
void primefactor(int x)
{
 // initalize a int with a static value of 2
    static int i=2;

// if i less then or equal to x
    if(i<=x)
    {
// while x%i doess equal 0 you have found a factor print factor
        while(x%i ==0)
        {
            cout<<i<<" x ";
// x takes a new value of x / i
            x=x/i;

        }
// increment i and call fuction again
        i++;
        primefactor(x);
    }

}
```

Comment: You can save primes you've found to some vector for example and then reverse it and print result.

Comment: I don't see that the code you show is printing a `*` anywhere, where does this come from? Did you mean `x` instead?

Comment: yes I meant "X" instead

Comment: ill just use a stack thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

To remove the trailing `x`, you can print it out conditionally:

```
while ((x % i) == 0)
{
    std::cout << i;
    x /= i;
    if (x > 1)
        std::cout << " x ";
}
```

Also, you can remove the `static` if you make `i` be an input parameter instead:

```
void primefactor(int x, int i = 2)
{
    ...
    primefactor(x, ++i);
    ...
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/DEXV8U)

But, to reverse the output is a little tricky for this kind of recursion.  If you can use an iterative loop instead of a recursive loop, then you can use a local `std::vector` to accumulate the factors and then reverse their order before printing them, eg:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

void primefactor(int x)
{
    std::vector<int> v;
    int i = 2;
 
    while (i <= x)
    {
        while ((x % i) == 0)
        {
            v.push_back(i);
            x /= i;
        } 
        ++i;
    }
 
    if (!v.empty())
    {
        std::reverse(v.begin(), v.end());
        std::cout << v[0];  
        for(size_t idx = 1; idx < v.size(); ++idx)
            std::cout << " x " << v[idx];
    }
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/O20fG2)

But, if you absolutely need a recursive function, you can still use a `std::vector`, just pass it around to each iteration, eg:

```
void primefactor_loop(int x, int i, std::vector<int> &v)
{
    if (i <= x)
    {
        while ((x % i) == 0)
        {
            v.push_back(i);
            x /= i;
        }
        primefactor_loop(x, ++i, v);
    }
}
 
void primefactor(int x)
{
    std::vector<int> v;

    primefactor_loop(x, 2, v);

    if (!v.empty())
    {
        std::reverse(v.begin(), v.end());
        std::cout << v[0];  
        for(size_t idx = 1; idx < v.size(); ++idx)
            std::cout << " x " << v[idx];
    }
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/O9V4cB)